# Angular 2 with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, angular, api, typescript

I tried using Facebook API for logging users in to my Angular-2 application . I am getting an error in my typescript file . 'Cannot find name FB'.

```
    (<any>window).fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
            appId      : '123456789012345',
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.8'
            });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });   
        };
```

Can anybody provide a solution to this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: well, is there an object named FB present? Has it been loaded? Is it a runtime error?

Comment: @BobbyTables Hi Bobby .. The object FB is created when the function is called . It is a compile time error . When I give the same code inside script tags in an HTML file , it works .

But if I type the same code inside a function in an Angular Service , It says **Cannot find name FB** . I am looking for a way to avoid this error in typescript file  .

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare a constant to use facebook SDK with angular.

Declare FB constant right above component declaration.

```
declare var FB: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
```

Then initialise facebook SDK inside your constructor function.

Comment: even with this approach, it turns out that sometimes the facebook SDK needs some time to load, and the FB variable isn't present yet at the time of calling the constructor.

Comment: So to handle this case, we somehow need to add a callback once our FB sdk file is loaded. I agree this is not a great solutions but this issue will happen in any framework and not only in angular in case of slow network.